# count unique combination in one column using Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i have a dataframe which i'm trying to create new columns showing the occurrence of different combinations within different groups. Solutions I've found are all combinations of values across 2 or more columns instead of one. Therefore, is hoping somebody can help.

sample df:

```
╔════╦═════╗
║ id ║ tag ║
╠════╬═════╣
║ a  ║   1 ║
║ a  ║   1 ║
║ a  ║   2 ║
║ a  ║   2 ║
║ a  ║   3 ║
║ a  ║   3 ║
║ b  ║   2 ║
║ b  ║   2 ║
║ b  ║   2 ║
║ b  ║   3 ║
║ b  ║   3 ║
║ b  ║   3 ║
╚════╩═════╝
```

output hope to get:

```
╔════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╗
║ id ║ tag ║ 1,1 ║ 1,2 ║ 1,3 ║ 2,2 ║ 2,3 ║ 3,3 ║
╠════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╣
║ a  ║   1 ║   1 ║   4 ║   4 ║   1 ║   4 ║   1 ║
║ a  ║   1 ║   1 ║   4 ║   4 ║   1 ║   4 ║   1 ║
║ a  ║   2 ║   1 ║   4 ║   4 ║   1 ║   4 ║   1 ║
║ a  ║   2 ║   1 ║   4 ║   4 ║   1 ║   4 ║   1 ║
║ a  ║   3 ║   1 ║   4 ║   4 ║   1 ║   4 ║   1 ║
║ a  ║   3 ║   1 ║   4 ║   4 ║   1 ║   4 ║   1 ║
║ b  ║   2 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   3 ║   9 ║   3 ║
║ b  ║   2 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   3 ║   9 ║   3 ║
║ b  ║   2 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   3 ║   9 ║   3 ║
║ b  ║   3 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   3 ║   9 ║   3 ║
║ b  ║   3 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   3 ║   9 ║   3 ║
║ b  ║   3 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   3 ║   9 ║   3 ║
╚════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╝
```

sample df code:

```
data = {
    "id": ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    "tag": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

for clarification:
"col "x,y" is the combinations of the tag values grouped by the id" as mentioned by @Chrysophylaxs (thanks).

kindly advise

Comment: I don't understand what the columns represent?  Why is id=a, tag=1, col='1,1' have the value of 1?

Comment: Seemingly: col "x,y", is a transformation of the tag values grouped by the id. The outcome for each group (thus being broadcast across all the rows in the group) is the number of times x appears in the group times the number of times y appears in the group

Comment: @James, sorry i wasn't clear. As Chrysophylaxs answered, "col='x,y' is a transformation of the tag values by the the id."

Comment: I wrote an answer for you. It was a bit challenging to understand your problem, but I got it finally. Let me know if you have a question.

Comment: @ali bakhtiari, sorry, I should have mentioned my question is related to combinatorics. Your answer solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer here:

```
data = {
    "id": ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    "tag": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

from itertools import combinations

df['combinations'] = df.groupby(['id']).transform(lambda x: str(list(combinations(x.to_list(), 2))))
df['combinations'] = df['combinations'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('),', '*').replace(', ','-').replace('*',',').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(' ','')).str.split(',')
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['combinations'])

x = df2.explode('combinations')
x = x.drop('tag', axis=1).groupby(['id', 'combinations']).value_counts().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0)
df.merge(x, on='id', how='left').drop('combinations', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    id  tag 1-1 1-2 1-3 2-2 2-3 3-3
0   a   1   1.0 4.0 4.0 1.0 4.0 1.0
1   a   1   1.0 4.0 4.0 1.0 4.0 1.0
2   a   2   1.0 4.0 4.0 1.0 4.0 1.0
3   a   2   1.0 4.0 4.0 1.0 4.0 1.0
4   a   3   1.0 4.0 4.0 1.0 4.0 1.0
5   a   3   1.0 4.0 4.0 1.0 4.0 1.0
6   b   2   0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 9.0 3.0
7   b   2   0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 9.0 3.0
8   b   2   0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 9.0 3.0
9   b   3   0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 9.0 3.0
10  b   3   0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 9.0 3.0
11  b   3   0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 9.0 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of the other answer:

```
s = df.groupby('id')['tag'].agg(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x,2))).explode()

(df.join(
    s.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0),s]).size().unstack()
    .rename('{0[0]}-{0[1]}'.format,axis=1),on = 'id')
.fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
   id  tag  1-1  1-2  1-3  2-2  2-3  3-3
0   a    1  1.0  4.0  4.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
1   a    1  1.0  4.0  4.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
2   a    2  1.0  4.0  4.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
3   a    2  1.0  4.0  4.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
4   a    3  1.0  4.0  4.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
5   a    3  1.0  4.0  4.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
6   b    2  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  9.0  3.0
7   b    2  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  9.0  3.0
8   b    2  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  9.0  3.0
9   b    3  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  9.0  3.0
10  b    3  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  9.0  3.0
11  b    3  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  9.0  3.0
```